# Cross-slide with nested scrollviewers in WinRT Xaml

Tags: listview, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

I am building an application which requires a horizontal list of vertical lists

Simplified XAML layout:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am having trouble getting the touch interactions right. Currently horizontal swipes move the entire list horizontally, and vertical move individual lists' items vertically. However it is possible to move *both* lists with a diagonal swipe, and it's not possible to scroll multiple vertical lists at a time (it is without the outer scrollviewer).

Is there a way to make all horizontal swipes apply only to the outer scrollviewer, and all vertical swipes only to an inner listview?

Answer (score 1):

You might get the desired effect if you set [`IsHorizontalRailEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.ishorizontalrailenabled.aspx)/[`IsVerticalRailEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.isverticalrailenabled.aspx) properties on both ScrollViewers.

You can also set something like `ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled` on a `GridView` or `ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled` on a `ListView` without having to extract the templates to get access to their `ScrollViewers`.

Comment: thank you a lot! Spent 3 hour searching internet for answer to "What does ``IsHorizontalRailEnabled`` do?". I even didn't need it, but was trying to find. (Will die one day from curiosity)